# Javascript "export default" to a class within the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, containers

I am familiar with the use `export default ExampleFunc` so that *ExampleFunc* can be imported in a different file as `import Func from 'filename.js'`.

However, I have come across a usage of `export default` which exports an object to a class within the same file. Does the following code instantiate a Container object?

```
import ExampleComp from 'file.js';

class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    dostuff;
  }
}

export default ExampleComp({key:value})(Container)
```

Comment: don't you want to instantiate the Container class when passing it to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the following code instantiate a `Container` object?

**That** code doesn't, no, but it may result in one or more being created, depending on what the code in the function `ExampleComp` returns does with the argument it receives: If the function `ExampleComp` returns creates an instance (or multiple instances) by using `new` with what it receives, then yes. If it doesn't, then no. (That said, it seems unlikely that it takes that parameter if it isn't going to use it to create instances...)

Let's break down what `ExampleComp({key:value})(Container)` does:

- It creates an object: `{key:value}`
- It passes that object into the function `ExampleComp` as an argument; apparently (from the code), `ExampleComp` returns a function
- It calls the function it got as the return value from `ExampleComp`, passing in `Container`
- It exports the return value of *that* call as the default export

Comment: @fermi - `Container` is passed as an argument to the function `ExampleComp` returns, I've added to the answer to address that code.

Comment: So basically, [currying](http://codekirei.com/posts/currying-with-arrow-functions/)!

Comment: @fermi - Well, not all functions that return functions are currying, but along those lines, yeah.